# How to position a submenu relative to its parent?

Tags: user-interface, drop-down-menu, submenu

I am designing a multi-column nested menu control. I'm trying to figure out where to position flying out sub menu. The submenu is currently flying out on hovering over the '>', not the text of the item.

Suppose this is the menu.

```
-------------------
|item 1 >|item 2 >|
|item 3 >|item 3 >|
-------------------
```

Option 1:

```
-------------------
|item 1 >|item 2 >|
|item -------------------
------|item 1.1|item 1.2|
      |item 1.3|item 1.4|
      -------------------
```

Option 2:

```
-------------------
|item 1 >|item 2 >|
-------------------
|item 1.1|item 1.2|
|item 1.3|item 1.4|
-------------------
```

Option 3:

```
-------------------
|item 1 >|-------------------
|item 3 >||item 1.1|item 1.2|
----------|item 1.3|item 1.4|
          -------------------
```

Option 4:

```
-----------------------------
|item 1 >||item 1.1|item 1.2|
|item 3 >||item 1.3|item 1.4|
-----------------------------
```

Which one do you think is more user-friendly?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that none of the options are viable. What you need is to position the box 1.5 lines below  the item you are hovering over so that if you mouse down, you will not get stuck on the open box. Same actually applies for horizontal E.g:

```
-------------------
|item 1 >|item 2 >|
|item    |        |
--------------+------------------
              |item 1.1|item 1.2|
              |item 1.3|item 1.4|
              -------------------
```

I can't show half a line in ascii but you should get the idea hopefully

Comment: It has just occurred to me that this might have been what you were referring to in option 3, sorry my bad. But the horizontal aspect still applies.